# Website responds different after migration from directadmin to plesk

Tags: php, plesk, directadmin

A little bit explaination of how I work to make my question clear.
I maintain a website. Local I create my changes with Xampp. When everything works I move the changed files to the production environment online.
Before we had directadmin as platform where the website is running. When an bug was found, I was able to reproduce this local.

Because the hoster was bankrupt we found a new hoster and migrated everything to there. The biggest difference is that they have Plesk as platform instead of DirectAdmin. Since the migration I had to change some things in my .htaccess and had some other issues but fixed them too.
I noticed that bugs on the Plesk cant be reproduced local.
The PHP versions are the same.

Do anyone know what can explain this different behaviour in running on DirectAdmin and Plesk when the versions are the same?
And second do anyone have a suggestion for local development which works equal to Plesk so I am able to debug more easy?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you confirm if the hosting provider uses Windows or Linux under the hood?

Comment: @msrumon Linux (Plesk), Linux (DirectAdmin, doesnt support Windows)

Comment: Can you prepare an example project which glitches out in the hosting environment and you can't reproduce that on local machine?

Comment: To me the description sounds as if there are some simple path issues in the website configuration.